# Report for visitors who fired more than one Event

Tags: events, google-analytics

I am looking to filter my data to look at only visitors who completed two or more events. For example suppose I have set up two events

Event 1 - Visitor clicks a particular link
Event 2 - Visitor adds an item to Basket

I want to look at the data only for visitors that did both of these things, in any order. How do I do this?

Secondly, is it possible to look at visitors who record hits on two different Event Labels within one Event Category?

To give you an idea of what I am trying to do. I want to set up an Event to track Optimizely experiments. The Event Category will be "Optimizely". The Event Label will be the experiment number and Event Action will be the number of the variation that they saw. I want to look at the data for visitors who overlapped from one experiment to another.

Answer (score 0):

Has your GA account been upgraded to Unified Segments rather than Advanced Segments? If so, you could build an advanced segment using Sequences.

Comment: Will a sequence work if I am using the same criteria for both parts e.g. 1. Event Label equals x and then 2. Event Label equals y ? I assume I will need to use an OR and do both directions to cover all cases?